# How to return null instead of exception message in Mule 3

Tags: mule

Could someone please help how to return null instead of returning exception as output json.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9097" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <validation:config name="Validation_Configuration" doc:name="Validation Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM SALESIT_DB.SALESIT_SC3VIS_BR.abcd  trx where trx.employee_id= '1232' and trx.so_number='abc']]></db:dynamic-query>
        </db:select>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="3581fe3a-a6f9-4071-b861-fcf16396358a">
            <dw:input-payload  mimeType="application/java"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[

%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload filter (($.payload != 0)) 

]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

exception is Numeric value 'abc' is not recognized (net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException).

IS there way we can print null as output payload instead of printing exception.

Can someone Help.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the db:select into a separate flow and then invoke it using flow reference.
2. Define a `catch-exception-strategy` in the extracted flow and within it setPayload to null.